# ¿Cómo puedo crear una gráfica de barras con FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

quiero hacer una gráfica de barras dentro de un pdf, he estado buscando pero solo encontré Gráfica de pastel (PieChart) el que necesito es de barras (Bar Char), como pudiera crearlo, o con alguna librería externa, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Aqui damos soluciones a problemas específicos de código más bien. Y no veo tu código por ninguna parte. Lo que pides lo solucionas en cualquier buscador. No somos google ni vamos a googlear por ti. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son bien recibidas y van a cerrarte la pregunta muy pronto.

Comment: Checa esta documentacion http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script28.php